# Problem with heap in lwext4 library when using journaling

Tags: c, memory-leaks, filesystems, heap-memory

I found out problem with no releasing heap memory in lwext4 library (https://github.com/gkostka/lwext4). But this problem appears only when writing into one specified file. This allocated memory is never released.
It seems that every write operations allocates cca 50 bytes, which is not released.
Writting to other files works correctly (but it is possible that there may be more such files with unreleasing heap memory in the file system).

During my investigation, I found that all unreleased blocks of heap memory were allocated within the following functions:

- jbd_journal_new_trans()
- jbd_trans_set_block_dirty()
- jbd_trans_insert_block_rec()

of the ext4_journal.c module.

I am using following constants in configuration header file of lwext4:

```
    #define CONFIG_EXT_FEATURE_SET_LVL F_SET_EXT3

    #define CONFIG_JOURNALING_ENABLE 1
    #define CONFIG_XATTR_ENABLE 0
    #define CONFIG_EXTENTS_ENABLE 0
    #define CONFIG_HAVE_OWN_ERRNO 0
    #define CONFIG_DEBUG_PRINTF 1
    #define CONFIG_DEBUG_ASSERT 1
    #define CONFIG_HAVE_OWN_ASSERT 1
    #define CONFIG_BLOCK_DEV_ENABLE_STATS 1
    #define CONFIG_BLOCK_DEV_CACHE_SIZE 1
    #define CONFIG_EXT4_MAX_BLOCKDEV_NAME 32
    #define CONFIG_EXT4_BLOCKDEVS_COUNT 2
    #define CONFIG_EXT4_MAX_MP_NAME 32
    #define CONFIG_EXT4_MOUNTPOINTS_COUNT 2
    #define CONFIG_HAVE_OWN_OFLAGS 0
    #define CONFIG_MAX_TRUNCATE_SIZE (16ul * 1024ul * 1024ul)
    #define CONFIG_UNALIGNED_ACCESS 0
    #define CONFIG_USE_USER_MALLOC 0
```

The problems will disappear after preparing a version with the journaling functionality disabled (disabling CONFIG_JOURNALING_ENABLE option), but I think that this is not the right solution of this problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You should file an issue on on the GitHub page and discuss it there.